# How to define POM location in Jenkins that is installed on a remote PC

Tags: jenkins

I have jenkins installed on a remote machine. How can I point my POM location in Jenkins. If I give the POM.xml location as C:\Automation\pom.xml I am getting the error no such file exists.

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Users\Administrator\.jenkins\workspace\RegressionTestJob
Parsing POMs
ERROR: No such file C:\Automation\pom.xml 
Perhaps you need to specify the correct POM file path in the project configuration?
TestNG Reports Processing: START
Looking for TestNG results report in workspace using pattern: **/testng-results.xml
Did not find any matching files.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Is the job running on master?

Comment: This is the first time I have setup Jenkins on a remote machine. I am not too sure when you say Master ? Thanks

Comment: Never mind about "master", not sure what I was thinking. Look at the configuration for the job you are running. Does it mention "C:\Automation\pom.xml" anyplace? For example, it might mention "mvn -f C:\Automation\pom.xml".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pom should be in your workspace, like how you would build your project in an IDE e.g. eclipse and when you build your project Jenkins will find the pom on its own in the workspace and build the project

Incase you still wish to specify the location you can use the -f option

`mvn -f PomFile.xml`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will try and let you know